# How to Delete controller ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, controller

I dynamically create controllers in my application like this:

```
var loadedController = me.app.getController(controller_name);
            loadedController.init();
```

How can I delete this controller after using?
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ExtJs currently does not support removal of controllers out of the box. To cleanup a controller, do the following:

- Extend `Ext.app.EventBus` with a method `uncontrol` that unregisters all event listeners that this controller registered on the EventBus. Check out the source of `Ext.app.EventBus#control` to derive an implementation. Or use [this one](https://github.com/mitchellsimoens/SubAppDemo/blob/master/assets/overrides/Ext.app.EventBus.js).
- Extend `Ext.app.Application` with a method `removeController` that removes a given controller instance from the `controllers` collection. It's a Ext.util.MixedCollection, check out the source for `Ext.app.Application#getController`. Then clean up all registered listeners for that controller using `uncontrol`.
- Implement a `destroy` method either on your specific controller and/or extend `Ext.app.Controller`. You should at least call `clearManagedListeners()` and possibly destroy other objects created by this controller like views or stores, if that suits your application architecture and controller life-cycle.

Comment: Good answer, you dug deeper into the topic :)

Comment: Good answer! That should be placed to feature request at sencha

Comment: Good answer, you covered everything which has to be deleted :) How do you test if the controller is really deleted?

Comment: Are you asking how to check if a specific JavaScript object has been garbage collected by the JavaScript engine?

Answer (score 2):

A Premium Member request has been initiated on the Sencha forums. Unfortunately, the original request has been there since August with no word. I've just bumped that request with reference to this thread.

[The Sencha Forum Topic (Premium section)](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238040)

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy any Ext class with `obj.destroy()`. 
Remember to also remove all references to the object so it can be garbage-collected.

Answer (score 0):

[getController()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getController) method creates a new controller object and stores reference to it in `controllers` array.

That means, if the controller is loaded using [getController()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getController), it will not be deleted, because there will always be at least one reference to it stored in `controllers` property of Application object.

To load controller in such way that it will be destroyed (free the memory it occupies) as soon as it will lose any references to existing objects (DOM elements, Ext components, its views, etc) one should use [Ext.create](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-create) instead of [getController()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-method-getController).
Here is the code:

```js
var loadedController = Ext.create(
     me.app.getModuleClassName(controller_name, 'controller'),
     {
         application: me.app,
         id: Ext.id(null, 'controller')
     }
);
loadedController.init(me.app);
loadedController.onLaunch(me.app);
```

`loadedController` will be local variable and will get out from scope. The only thing which will continue to bind newly created controller to 'real life' will be the elements the controller creates itself.
For example, controller may create a new view in his [onLaunch()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-onLaunch) method, which will be injected into DOM, and controller will listen to view events using handlers bind in his [init()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-method-init) method. As long as view will exist, controller will exist too. But when user closes the view, view will be destroyed and since it was the last reference to our controller, controller will be destroyed, too.

**UPDATE**
Listeners created with controller are being appended to [Ext.app.EventBus](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.EventBus) and may prevent automatic removal of controller, because they also may keep references to that controller.